# Pooling unequal numbers of survey years

Tags: time-series, survey, difference-in-difference, pooling

I am analyzing how health insurance disparities changed following January 1, 2014, using a large, nationally representative survey with complex design. I have access to many years of data but 2014 is the most recent year available.

As hypothesized, I am seeing strong trends when I compare 2013 with 2014, but very wide confidence intervals, so I'm hoping to pool years to tighten the errors and reduce the chance of Type II error.

Because 2014 is the latest year of data available for this survey, I would only be able to pool years prior to 2014 for this analysis. So, I am wondering if there is anything wrong with pooling survey data from years 2012 and 2013, and comparing the result with the unpooled numbers from 2014? I can't think of anything wrong with this conceptually or mathematically but I also can't find examples of people pooling years asymmetrically like this.

Thank you!

Comment: How would the pooling work? It seems like you should use time series methods here.

Comment: Pooling would be done by combining 2012-2013 and dividing the weights by two. That part is pretty standard in complex survey design research.

As for time series, the reason I don't want to do that is because I'm curious about the change in 2014 specifically, not the gradual change over three years.

Comment: It should be possible to model a change since Jan 1, 2014 specifically using time series methods.

Comment: Huh.. is there a method you could point me towards that would accomplish that?

Comment: It's better if others w/ more time series expertise advised you on that. But I'll add the tag, which will draw their attention.